# Tls message python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, ssl, tls1.2

Is there a way to know how ssl library make ssl or tls message i have captured the message on some request but i really don't understand this message is there a way to write it instead of using ssl library

```
import socket
host = 'fast.com'
port = '443'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(1)
s.connect((str(host), int(port)))
s.sendall(b"\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xfc\x03\x03x4\xe2f\xdfl\x15\x05\xda\xa5\x8f9p\xd8\x1d+\xd7?+\xf2\xe4\xce\xcf\xa3\nn\xcb\x8eNm\x8e\xa9\x00\x00r\xc00\xc0,\xc0(\xc0$\xc0\x14\xc0\n\x00\xa5\x00\xa1\x00\x9f\x00k\x00i\x00h\x009\x007\x006\x00\x88\x00\x86\x00\x85\xc02\xc0.\xc0*\xc0&\xc0\x0f\xc0\x05\x00\x9d\x00=\x005\x00\x84\xc0/\xc0+\xc0'\xc0#\xc0\x13\xc0\t\x00\xa4\x00\xa0\x00\x9e\x00g\x00?\x00>\x003\x001\x000\x00E\x00C\x00B\xc01\xc0-\xc0)\xc0%\xc0\x0e\xc0\x04\x00\x9c\x00<\x00/\x00A\x00\xff\x01\x00\x01a\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x10\x00\x00\rm.youtube.com\x00\x0b\x00\x04\x03\x00\x01\x02\x00\n\x00\x1c\x00\x1a\x00\x17\x00\x19\x00\x1c\x00\x1b\x00\x18\x00\x1a\x00\x16\x00\x0e\x00\r\x00\x0b\x00\x0c\x00\t\x00\n\x00#\x00\x00\x00\r\x00 \x00\x1e\x06\x01\x06\x02\x06\x03\x05\x01\x05\x02\x05\x03\x04\x01\x04\x02\x04\x03\x03\x01\x03\x02\x03\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\x02\x03\x00\x0f\x00\x01\x01\x00\x15\x00\xf2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
print(s.recv(1024))
```

Comment: Sure you can implement TLS yourself. Just follow the standard, it is all in there. Note that it isn't trivial, i.e. far far away from just replaying a captured ClientHello as you seem to do. And because it is so far far away the question is too broad.

Comment: Ok but how to do that in other way how ssl library make and write this message

Comment: I wonder to know how ssl library make this message and the form of server_hostname (sni) here in this message the sni is m.youtube.com if i changed it to any thing like www.youtube.com it will be refused so the message is formed on a way to complicat the sni

Comment: This is all defined in the standard. As for `server_name` see [RFC 6066](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6066#section-3).  For the basics of the ClientHello message see [RFC 5246 section 7.4.1.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2). And again, starting with the little bit of knowledge you show in your question this is too broad.